# AEM/CQ: UI for one-off JCR-SQL / SQL2 / XPath queries with tabular output?

Tags: aem, jcr-sql2

I am doing a little usage research in our AEM installation. I would like to find all instances of a component and see what value they have for a certain configuration option. So basically, I want to select the `title` and `myOption` properties from all nodes with `sling:resourceType` `myComponent`.

I believe the JCR-SQL2 query would be:

```
SELECT [title], [myProperty] FROM [nt:base]
where [sling:resourceType] like 'path/to/my/component'
```

My problem is, I can't find a UI in which to run this query.

- **The CRX:DE Query tool** (CRX:DE > Tools > Query) accepts XPath or SQL2, but **only shows me the path to the matching nodes.** Sure I can click on each one to zoom to that node, but that's tedious. I want a tabular output with title and property value.
- **The Query Builder Debugger** (`/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html`) **uses its own URL-based query syntax and only outputs JSON.** I recreated the query in terms of URL parameters...

  ```
  property=sling:resourceType
  property.value=path/to/my/component
  p.hits=selective
  p.properties=title myProperty
  p.limit=-1
  ```

  ... But I still don't want to write code to parse the JSON and display a table.
- I understand that I could write a class / component to display this but again, this is a one-off query and I am just digging around. I'd prefer not to have to write Java, JS, or JSP just to send and display this query.

So my question is...

**Is there another query UI buried somewhere in CQ that lets me put in one-off JCR-SQL / SQL2 / XPath queries with columns specified, and get a tabular output, the way you would with a SQL prompt or tool?**

I would settle for a query builder incantation to produce pretty-printed JSON, so I could at least eyeball the JSON results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bulk editor `/etc/importers/bulkeditor.html` . It is a great match for your requirement

Just set root path as `/content`, **uncheck content mode** and for query parameters use `"sling:resourceType":path/to/my/component`. Set custom properties to `title,myOption`. It display's the result in a table.

For more : http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/administering/bulk_editor.html

Bulk editor only works for simple queries,for complex queries you can try this : http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/query-editor.html .

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Groovy Console](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console). You may easily write a short script producing desired output:

```
def QUERY = "SELECT [jcr:lastModified], [jcr:title] FROM [nt:base] WHERE [sling:resourceType] = 'foundation/components/title'"

session.workspace.queryManager.createQuery(QUERY, "JCR-SQL2").execute().rows.each { r ->
    println r.values.collect { it.string }.join('\t')
}
```

Script can be simply pasted into the text area, no need to compile or upload anything to the server.

Comment: AEM Fiddle is essentially the same idea as Groovy Console, but lets you execute your code via JSPs (or any other script languages AEM supports) ... http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/aem-fiddle.html

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a report listing all the properties you need via a pretty UI builder using [Adobe's ACS Reports](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/report-builder/index.html) add-on which is part of the [ACS Commons](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/) bundle. You provide the JCR-SQL2 query and then pick the columns with your custom properties.

See:

- https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/report-builder/index.html